# Can I call C library functions from OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl

I am going to parallelize the process of Encryption/Decryption by using OpenCL.

For that I just want to use existing openSSL crypto library function instead of creating own algorithms like AES ,DES.

So that I am going to call a openSSL crypto function from OpenCL kernel.
Can you please clarify my query, is it possible or not?

Comment: @nouveau : It seems someone wrote an [implementation for OpenCL](http://www.itekia.com/blog/archive/2013/10/15/librsa-detail-sur-limplementation-de-librsa#body-anchor). You should send an e-mail to info@itekia dot com to get it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you are restricted to built-in functions and functions defined by yourself on kernel level. This becomes immediately clear (in case of a GPU), if you see host and device as two separate entitities which can only communicate through a command queue and its associated calls.

Comment: Note that most of the low-level cryptographic code in OpenSSL can be ready ported to the GPU with little modifications, the problem being how to redesign the API around a massively parallel architecture (the original OpenSSL init/update/final model fails spectacularly in this respect).

Comment: I agree with you, that OpenSSL's number crunching code can be ported to GPU architectures, but that's not what OP asked for.

Comment: I am not putting your answer into question (so to speak) in fact I upvoted it, I merely added a secondary note for the OP reading this answer, because the logical reaction after being told that "you cannot call X on the GPU" is going to be "how can I implement X on the GPU myself", and with respect to cryptography it is best to reuse existing code as much as possible.